# How to setup multi branch company in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: branch, openerp-7, accounts

I am trying to set up a service company with multiple branches [3] in OpenERP 7.0. The nature of business is same at all the branches, though a branch has only some departments. I was advised to use multi company module, but I am not convinced about using multiple companies and different chart of accounts of each company.
I am looking at having 1 chart of accounts, that is available at all branches, though some minor heads may be zero for them.

The BS and P&L of the company should reflect the summation of all the branches.
Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Companies --> Create Company --> give parent Company and add necessary details. Go to Settings --> Users --> Create Employee -> In access rights check multiple companies. It works